# Problem with logging user in without using ORM - "Could not locate column in row for column 'is_active'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I am trying to log user in without using ORM. My code looks like that:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def index():
        if flask.request.method == 'POST':
            email = request.form.get('email')
            password = flask.request.values.get('password')
            user = db.execute("SELECT * from users WHERE email = :email", {'email': email}).first()
            if user is None or not check_password_hash(user._password, password):
                flash("Invalid password or username")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
            login_user(user, remember=True)
        return render_template('index.html')
```

And what I get after trying to log in:

> AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'is_active'

saying that the problem is in the line:

```
login_user(user, remember=True)
```

Is there something wrong with this code, or the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of [flask-login extension](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) your user class has to implement, among others `is_active` property.

Since these requirements are fairly generic, you can use `UserMixin` mixin from `flask_login` for your User class.

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    #  your fields email, etc...
    pass
```

and query User objects like: 
`user = User.query.filter_by(email=request.form.get('email')).first()`

You can read more about it in this excellent tutorial: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

Comment: Yes, I know, I managed to do this with ORM (with user=User.query.filter_by ...) but I am trying to understand different approach, and I don't get why it isn't working

Comment: user passed to `login_user` must be User class instance, not `RowProxy` from sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement methods which flask_login expects by your own. They described at https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class

Or check your load_user function. Is it returns User class instance and None otherwise?